# Can not create label on Inno Setup Welcome page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to create a label (or a bitmap) on the welcome page using this code:

```pascal
LabelTarget := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
with LabelTarget do
begin
  Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
  Left := ScaleX(198);
  Top := ScaleY(105);
  Caption := 'Target';
end;
```

It won't work, but if I change the parent for example to `WizardForm.InstallingPage` it will create that label on Installing page. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because almost whole area of the `WelcomePage` is covered by an opaque `WelcomeLabel2`.

The `TLabel` is not a *real* Windows control. It is a *virtual* one, drawn by the form itself. So it gets hidden by any other *real* Windows control, even if the `TLabel` is technically on top of it (what it is, as your `LabelTarget` is created later than the `WelcomeLabel2`). The `WelcomeLabel2` is `TStaticText`, what is a *real* control. So it hides your  `LabelTarget`.

To solve this either:

- Shrink the `WelcomeLabel2` height, or
- Change your `LabelTarget` to `TStaticText`.